# How to convert an UTC datetime string into a local datetime in Dart?

Tags: dart, datetime, utc, localtime

I got this value from an API `2022-03-15T02:33:53.488427`, it is a string which represents a UTC timestamp, my current zone time is UTC-5, I'm trying this code:

```
createdAt = DateTime.tryParse('2022-03-15T02:33:53.488427').toLocal();
```

But `createdAt` contains the same datetime like the original string, What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the string 2022-03-15T02:33:53.488427 does not include a timezone. So to tell Dart that you want this to be UTC time, then append a "Z" to the string. Then it knows that it is Zulu time. Otherwise it's going to assume that you are in local time when it parses it.
try

```
createdAt = DateTime.tryParse('2022-03-15T02:33:53.488427Z').toLocal();
```

Use print(createdDate?.timeZoneName) to confirm UTC or your local